# Navigation bar not centering

Tags: html, css

HTML :

```
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="Index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="History">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="Appointments">Appointments</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contactus">Contact us</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS :

```
nav {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
display: center;}


nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #Cc3399;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;

}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #a2b3a1;
    color: #000
}
```

Basically, I've managed to make this navigation bar, that fits my specifications. However, it's not centered, it's in position vertically, but horizontally it's way left and no where near the center of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to replace `inline` to `inline-block` and use `text-align: center` to parent(also `display: center` is not valid css):

```css
nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;/*add text align-center*/
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;/*replace inline to inline-block*/
}
nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #Cc3399;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #a2b3a1;
    color: #000
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="History">History</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Appointments">Appointments</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Contactus">Contact us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Will do, 3 minutes left on the timer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given margin as 100% for  it will not have impact on margin.. So try giving 50% width to  and it should work.
You can change like this...

```
nav
{
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 50%;
 display: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to horizontally center an element, this element needs to be display:block; and it should have a width that is less than 100%

Here is the css, slight modification based on what you have

```
nav {
    position: relative;

    /*** centers the nav block ****/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 20%;    /*** make the centering look more vivid ****/
    background: #Cc3399;
    color: #eee;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;

}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #a2b3a1;
    color: #000
}
```

You can view it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t3y0abm/3/)